# Mobile menu doesn't close on iPhone

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, safari, mobile-safari

I'm told that [the mobile menu on my page](http://goo.gl/0SFYva) (accessible through the 3 horizontal bars icon top right) doesn't close on iPhone. I can't check myself because I don't have Apple devices (on online iPhone simulators it does work though) but I don't see why it would work on Android and not on iPhone.

Here's the JS code controlling the mobile menu:

```
$( '#mobile_menu_icon' ).click(function() {
    if( $( '.mobile_header_menu' ).css( 'right' ) == '-280px' ) { 
        $( '.mobile_header_menu' ).animate( { right: '0' }, open_delay, 'easeInOutExpo' );  
        $( '#wrap' ).animate({ right: '280px' }, open_delay, 'easeInOutExpo' );
        $( 'body' ).addClass( 'overflow_hidden' );
    }
    else { 
        $( '.mobile_header_menu' ).animate({ right: '-280px' }, close_delay, 'easeInOutExpo' );
        $( '#wrap' ).animate({ right: '0' }, close_delay, 'easeInOutExpo' );    
        $( 'body' ).removeClass( 'overflow_hidden' );
    }
    return false;
});
$( document, '.mobile_header_menu_close' ).click(function() {
    if( $( '.mobile_header_menu' ).css( 'right' ) == '0px' ) {
        $( '.mobile_header_menu' ).animate({ right: '-280px' }, close_delay, 'easeInOutExpo' );
        $( '#wrap' ).animate({ right: '0' }, close_delay, 'easeInOutExpo' );
        $( 'body' ).removeClass( 'overflow_hidden' );   
    }
});
$( '.mobile_header_menu_inner' ).click(function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: If this is a JS or HTML question you should add the appropriate tag. I'm not a web developer so I don't know the answer to your question. I don't even remember what a "Hamburger Menu" is. I've heard the term, but don't remember what it is. You might want to edit your question and offer more background, as this site is mostly for native app developers, not web designers.

Comment: Because Safari is a different browser? Period :) I changed your tags..

Comment: Works fine on desktop Safari though. Why the downvote? There are millions of pretty similar questions on stackoverflow without downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed the following piece and it worked. Don't understand why it was problematical on iPhones.

```
$( '.mobile_header_menu_inner' ).click(function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It works just fine.

(Tested on iOS 9.1, 9.0 and 8.4 on the Xcode simulator and a iPhone 6 (iOS 9.1) and iPad Air (9.0)).

Comment: Well two different people with iPhones said it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you know what version of the operating system they were using? It's an interesting bug to take into account in future projects.